# Advantage PHP PDO Driver on PHP7

Tags: php, pdo, php-7, advantage-database-server

How can I install advantage PHP PDO driver on PHP7 on Ubuntu Server 14.04?

I have followed the instructions here:

https://devzone.advantagedatabase.com/dz/webhelp/Advantage11/index.html

But I'm having an error when trying to execute the `make` command

`/var/www/php-7.0.9/ext/advantage/php_ads.c: In function ‘zif_ads_tableprivileges’:
/var/www/php-7.0.9/ext/advantage/php_ads.c:4065:31: error: expected expression before ‘ads_connection’
ZEND_FETCH_RESOURCE2(conn, ads_connection *, &pv_conn, -1, "Advantage-Link", le_conn, le_pconn);
make: *** [ext/advantage/php_ads.lo] Error 1`

Comment: Does the vendor list the extension as being compatible with PHP7? There were many changes to the internals of PHP in 7.0, and extensions generally need substantial work to be compatible.

Comment: They haven't listed it, it just says PHP Driver. There is also a separate driver for PHP5.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a PDO driver but i developed a driver for PHP7. You have to compile this driver into PHP yourself though. See this repo.

=> https://github.com/k1ln/ADSforPHP7

you need the Advantage Setup files for this. These I cannot deliver. Take the php 5 driver and change the files in the repo. Then you can use php7 with Advantage Database